# cp command in macOS doesn't create a new folder if it doesn't exist

Tags: macos

`cp -R /Desktop/One.java /Desktop/Nine`

The folder `Nine` is not created. Instead, a new file `Nine` is created without any extension.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

If `cp` is used with `-R`, then the target (`/Desktop/Nine`) is created with the same file type as the source (regular file).  If the source is a directory (it isn't), the full directory hierarchy will be copied.

In your case, the source is a single regular file, in which case `cp -R` will act identically as `cp` (with no `-R`).

If you want to copy the file `/Desktop/One.java` into a new directory `/Desktop/Nine`:

```
mkdir /Desktop/Nine
cp /Desktop/One.java /Desktop/Nine
```

Comment: Good explanation. I think he's trying to create a new directory and put the `One.java` file into it.

Comment: @styl3r That's a possibility. I'll mention how to do that.